# JMS Serializer not reading config when running PHPUnit tests in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, phpunit, jmsserializerbundle, serialization

I'm using JMSSerializer to create JSON  responses for a Symfony2 project I'm working on and a trying to build unit tests for each response but I'm hitting variations of the below:

```
JMS\Serializer\Exception\RuntimeException: You must define a type for FooBundle\Entity\Bar::$name.
```

I'm using YML config for the serializer and it works perfectly when generating responses.

```
#src/FooBundle/Resources/config/serializer/Entity.Bar.yml
FooBundle\Entity\Bar:
  exclusion_policy: none
    properties:
        id:
            exclude: true
            type: integer
        name:
            type: string
```

I wondered if I need to preload the config somehow and found this link: 
http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/configuration that says to configure a metadata path but also to include a file suffix:

```
$serializer =
JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder::create()
    ->addMetadataDir($someDir)
    ->build();
```

I've tried setting the config directory when generating the serializer in the unit test:

```
$serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()->addMetadataDir('path-to-dir')->build();
```

But this didn't resolve the problem, I checked the documentation page again and it tells you to list a full path to a file

"So, if you class would be named Vendor\Package\Foo, the metadata file would need to be located at $someDir/Vendor.Package.Foo.(xml|yml)."

but trying get generates:

```
JMS\Serializer\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: The directory "path-to-file" does not exist.
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks

Ben

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JMSSerializer caches the configuration files the first time it reads them, you have to clear the test environment's cache with:

```
php app/console cache:clear -e test
```